# How to delete duplicate points in computer generated tikz image

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, svg

I used an svg file of an image as the basis for a program ([this](https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/svg-to-tex) one, I think) to generate a tikz version of the image. The tikz code it produced compiles correctly and the image looks good, but the code is massively redundant and takes a long time to process. Very frequently it will repeat coordinates inside of filldraw commands, like in the snippet shown below.

```
\filldraw[color_137559][nonzero rule]
(-15pt, -378.75pt) -- (-15pt, -378.75pt)
 -- (-15pt, -378.75pt)
 -- (-15pt, -379.5pt)
 -- (-15pt, -379.5pt)
 -- (-12pt, -379.5pt)
 -- (-12pt, -379.5pt)
 -- (-15pt, -378.75pt) -- cycle
;
```

At over 50000 lines long the code is too big to fix manually. Is there a way to remove the duplicated coordinates to shorten the code? Or is there a better way to generate a more efficient tikz image from my svg files? As it currently exists the file is big enough that it is interfering with externalizing any of the tikz images in my project.

Edit: Images included via svg: [Image 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t4n82rRjZrAQsyWHG_t5mUSTWbb8IhsP/view?usp=sharing), [Image 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vmgj1UuevJT2Cmu5e7Pe1J2mE7Uun6J8/view?usp=sharing)
Full tikz code included: [Image 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/100EYOCph6FyGW1Hvotal02P_dFT0_2zQ/view?usp=sharing), [Image 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iDSoYTWAadC0r_BhWl0vUnJluyT_JH6Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please add the original image to your question, which said webpage processed? Thank you.

Comment: if they are exact duplicates as there I guess a few lines of regular expression replace in perl or python or whatever would clean it up, but if you want to optimise away points whose location only differs by .000pt or whatever, it gets harder

Comment: I know that there exist some automated SVG optimization tools. I don't know about their quality, but I would assume that they can find such duplicate coordinates. So, maybe you can delete the duplicate coordinates already in the SVG code.

Comment: You can convert svg to bitmap(e.g. screenshot) in the desired resolution and then back to svg with a trace tool(e.g. Inkscape). This suggested method falls out of the scope of this site though.

Comment: I have added the svg files as requested, and also included the tex files with the tikz code. I tried using the uniq function on Terminal (I'm on a Mac), but the resulting file wouldn't compile.

Comment: Uhm, looking at the images you linked, it would probably a better idea to generate a PDF from the SVG and just place this into your document.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, that's probably a good suggestion in this case as I don't want to do too much manipulation to the images. It would be nice to have a method for cleaning up the code in case I did want to say, add a lovely mustache and a party hat to MM. Newton and Leibniz.

Comment: You can still use tikz to write over an image.   Just put `\includegraphics` in a named node and position additions relative to the node anchors.